# mvn test after update to java 19 brings [ERROR] Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm still working on a multi-module maven project which I upgraded from openJDK 15 to openJDK 19. I'm working on a MBP with macOS 13 Ventura.

Before the upgrade the unit test are passing with the maven-surefire-plugin without any problems.

After upgrading to openJDK 19 the `mvn clean test` command fails with the following error-message.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
[ERROR] java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.graphics not found, required by common
```

I downloaded the files (openJDK 19 and JavaFX 19), unzipped them to a desired location, added an environment variable pointing to the lib directory of the runtime.

I can run the program from IntelliJ without any problems.

My question is, what did I missed in the configuration to get the test running?

Comment: Please try with newer surefire version 3.0.0-M7

Comment: *"I downloaded the files (openJDK 19 and JavaFX 19), unzipped them to a desired location, added an environment variable pointing to the lib directory of the runtime."* -> why though?  It is a maven project, why not [reference JavaFX as Maven dependencies](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)?  Idea can create a [sample JavaFX Maven project for you](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) which you can use as a reference.  Trying to write unit tests for Java can be tricky, perhaps use [testfx](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX), linked page shows an example of usage.

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski Thank you so much. The newer version solves my issues.

Comment: @jewelsea "why though?" There is a JavaFX Maven Dependency in my project. There are also non-maven-projects that uses JavaFX on my machine.

Appreciate your hint to testfx. Unfortunately there is no need to test JavaFX components at the moment. Maybe later.

Comment: *"Unfortunately there is no need to test JavaFX components at the moment."* -> surefire is a test harness and the error you get is `Module javafx.graphics not found`.  That indicates that the test setup is dependent on JavaFX, even if you aren't explicitly testing JavaFX components. As the JavaFX modules are dependencies in your Maven project, I'd expect them to be found.  I guess whatever caused the modules not to be found was fixed by a Maven surefire plugin bug that was fixed by the upgrade suggested by @SlawomirJaranowski

Comment: "That indicates that the test setup is dependent on JavaFX, even if you aren't explicitly testing JavaFX components." I can't see the dependency in the test setup. The only JavaFX-dependency is a FileChooser.ExtensionFilter. They are implemented in the common module and not in the app module.

Answer (score 0):

My issues are gone with the advice from @Slavomir Jaranowski.

The changed pom looks like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--<skipTests>${skipUnitTests}</skipTests>-->
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        <forkCount>1.5C</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
        <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The configuration is not finished yet.